# Why does foo[F[_], A](ff: F[A]) accept foo(1)?

Tags: scala, type-constructor

Why does the call to `foo(1)` work in my Scala 2.11.7 repl as described below?

```
scala> def foo[F[_], A](fa: F[A]) = null
foo: [F[_], A](fa: F[A])Null

scala> foo(List(1))
res0: Null = null

scala> foo(1)
res1: Null = null
```

The parameter in my call to `foo(1)` is not a Type Constructor so why does the Scala repl accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo(1)` works because there is an implicit conversion [`int2Integer`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/7bfe4c09a5fc72d9ef8103c3e0a3cefb469fa14b/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L472) to `java.lang.Integer`

```
foo(int2Integer(1))
```

and `Integer` is an instance of `Comparable[Integer]`

```
public final class Integer extends Number implements Comparable<Integer>
```

where we see `Comparable` is indeed a type constructor. For example, we can [reproduce](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/KvxzOxVRTwCxVR2aegBKmA) the same behaviour like so

```
def foo[F[_], A](fa: F[A]) = 42
trait Bar // not a type constructor
implicit def barToComparable(b: Bar): Comparable[Int] = (o: Int) => -1
val bar = new Bar {}
foo(bar) // OK due to implicit conversion barToComparable
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `Int` is considered an instance of class `Any` (because is not a type constructor and so type hierarchy is analyzed to find a supertype that is also a type constructor), and class `Any` in Scala is considered a type constructor of type `Nothing`.

You can check this behavior with following code:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object Main {
  def foo[F[_], A](fa: F[A])(implicit ev: TypeTag[F[A]], ev2: TypeTag[A]) = {
    println(ev)
    println(ev2)
    println(ev.tpe.typeArgs)
    println()
    null
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]){
    foo(List(1))
    foo(1)
  }
}
```

Output:

```
TypeTag[List[Int]]
TypeTag[Int]
List(Int)

TypeTag[Any]
TypeTag[Nothing]
List()
```

Comment: The situation is much more weird. `case object A; foo(A)` doesn't work. If the issue was `Any` as you described - it would have worked. Also there are some implicit conversions in `Predef` like `ArrowAssoc`, which actually can contribute to being `F[_]`, but there are others. So I'd axpect the error mentioning that there are ambiguous implicit conversions, but it does not and it does accept `Int`, but not `object A`. Furthermore I've seen ambiguous implicit conversions error with a very similar code, but cannot reproduce it now unfortunately

Comment: I'll see into object conversion when I have some spare time.

Comment: So, if I define `foo` as `def foo[F[_], A](fa1: F[A], fa2: F[A])` and then call `foo(1, "hello")`, this is a legal call because both `1` and `"hello"` are type-constructors of type `Any`?

Comment: Yes, but I've tested and TypeTag[A] now prints Any, I'll check if Scala reference points to this behaviour.